# Lazy symbol binding failed in Xcode 8.3.3

Tags: ios, xcode8

My Application has deployment target 8.0. It works well with device running above iOS 10.0, but it gets crashed in the device running below iOS 10.0. Here is the error which I got from console

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _sqlite3_key
      Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/887A192E-F390-47F6-80F3-768F4F321C8A/xxxx.app/xxx
      Expected in: dyld shared cache
```

Below are the things I have tried to fix this, but nothing worked for me

- Force Cleaned the application.
- Reloaded the console.
- Added the following architectures (armv7s, arm64, armv7).
- Deleted the libsqlite3.tbd and added once again.
- Generating the build with distribution profile and installed the same in device and tried (Gone through in some threads and found it happens only in the DEBUG mode).

Comment: Are you using Pods?

Comment: No .... I'm using SAP SDK